# xcode 6: splash screen in Images.xcassets not found

Tags: ios8, xcode6, splash-screen

Like previous Xcode 5,
 
it had option of adding images that are visible as splash screen

 so how to add now in Xcode 6 (Not Beta version)?

any reference like video will be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default Xcode 6 will not have the XCAssets option. So you need to add the file into your project then you can add the splash screen images.